# Hello all. Is there a way to redirect to another page with Alert in react native?

Tags: react-native, expo

```
  const touchHandler = () => {
            if (true) {
                Alert.alert('Choose Action', 'Would you like to take a picture or select an existing one?', 
                [{ text: 'Select from gallery', 
                onPress: ()=> retrieveImageHandler }, {text: 'take a picture ' , onPress: ()=>{takeImageHandler}}]);
            
            }
```

OnPress button wont fire the fucntion retrieveImageHandler and takeImageHandler

Answer (score 1):

You may replce this

```
onPress: ()=> retrieveImageHandler
onPress: ()=>{takeImageHandler}
```

with

```
onPress: ()=> retrieveImageHandler()
onPress: ()=>{takeImageHandler()}
```

because when you call function with `()=>` you have to add brackets after function name like this `()=> functionName()`